# Html contents in a vaadin label

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Is it possible to draw html contents in vaadin label?

I have texts with `<br>` contents. Is it available to let the label to use them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [2 argument constructor of `Label`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Label.html#Label%28java.lang.String,%20com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.ContentMode%29) and set the [`ContentMode`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/shared/ui/label/ContentMode.html) to `HTML`.

Something like,

```
new Label(YOUR_HTML_TEXT, ContentMode.HTML);
```

From the Javadoc (linked above):

> Label component for showing non-editable short texts. The label
>   content can be set to the modes specified by ContentMode
>
> The contents of the label may contain simple formatting:
>
> - Bold
> - Italic
> - Underlined
> - Linebreak
> - ...

Comment: please be aware, that the documentation suggest, that some sanitation is done here, but it isn't.  you can e.g. use ``new Label('<code>Hello</code><a href="javascript:alert(1)">World</a>', ContentMode.HTML)`` and with this content beeing e.g. provided by user input creates a security problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.ContentMode;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;

Label htmlLabel = new Label("<h1>Header</h1><strike>text</strike>");
htmlLabel.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
```

This piece of code shows needed classes and calls to have HTML markup rendered properly in a vaadin's Label.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Obviously, this piece of code shows how to assign HTML content to a vaadin label and shows the required imports.